# Reporting template in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, report, visual-studio-2017

The Reporting template seems missing in VS2017 (I am using Visual Basic). Any way to get it back?

I have already tried installing SQL Server Data tools and the rdlc extension from the marketplace, but it still doesn't show up.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The template is available in the Add New Item window. Select Visual C# and then look for the Report and Report Wizard templates. These templates are only visible under Visual C#, not under any subitem.

Comment: For one, I am not using Visual C#, but VB.Net. For two, the reason I posted the question is because it is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating ReportViewer to version 14.0.0.0 and installing [Microsoft.RdlcDesigner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001). This worked for me for Visual C# and then just like J.Bunch said there is no sub item Reporting like there was before so you just scroll down thorough all items. Also try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started) although the example is for C# I think it should at least help you with VB.Net as well. Hope it helps.